# Parse JSON string inside of c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

OK there are a few posts about this...I haven't gotten them to work.

I have a simple object

```
{
    "Projects": "Projects",
    "Dashboard": "Dashboard",
    "Applications": "Applications",
    "Plans": "Plans",
    "Logout": "Logout"
}
```

I am trying to Deserialize it.  I have Newtonsoft available.

Here is what I have that doesn't work.

```
var languageString = "{"Projects":"Projects","Dashboard":"Dashboard","Applications":"Applications","Plans":"Plans","Logout":"Logout"}";
var objOut = new { name = "", lastname = "" };
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(languageString, objOut);
```

I keep getting an error on the anonymous object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting on the anonymous object?

Comment: 1. Your example code has syntax errors. 2. **What** error do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deserialize objects you need to be sure that the class or anonymous type used to deserialize them match source JSON string.

If you would have a JSON `{ "name": "john", "lastname": "smith" }`, your code should work:

```
// I expect no one to have concerns about the double quots (""): it's
// another way of escaping quots in C# (you should also use \" but it's
// uglier, isn't it? ;)
string jsonText = @"{ ""name"": ""john"", ""lastname"": ""smith"" }";
var sampleType = new { name = "", lastname = "" };
var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonText, sampleType );
```

### In your case...

...you would need a sample anonymous type instance like this:

```
var sampleType = new 
{
    Projects = "",
    Dashboard = "",
    Applications = "",
    Plans = "",
    Logout = ""
}
```

### ...or what about using a dynamic object?

You can also use `dynamic` deserializing objects to `ExpandoObject` and you won't need a sample type!

```
dynamic deserializedObject = 
       JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(languageString, new ExpandoObjectConverter());
```

Keep in mind that this is *duck typing*: you won't know if the deserialized object has the expected properties until run-time. BTW, well-documented code can do the trick, and if you expect the deserialized object to have a property like `lastname` you can access it directly with `deserializedObject.lastname`!

Comment: Your answer is correct. Just to understand the question I tried with  same data as in questions but i did not any error as mentioned in question "error on the anonymous object."

Comment: Don't you need an `@` in front of that string? You example does not compile for me otherwise.

Comment: @Prashant The question has unclear content, BTW, it seems like the OP is trying to deserialize another JSON than the given one in the question, and for now we can provide a generic advise about how to correctly deserialize into anonymous types...............

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's usually easier to deserialize into a strongly-typed class. Given the JSON you presented your deserialization class would look like:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Projects { get; set; }
    public string Dashboard { get; set; }
    public string Applications { get; set; }
    public string Plans { get; set; }
    public string Logout { get; set; }
}
```

Although this JSON is fairly simple, if it were more complex you can use http://json2csharp.com to automatically generate the C# class(es) from the JSON.

Then all you need to do is:

```
var languageString = "{\"Projects\":\"Projects\",\"Dashboard\":\"Dashboard\",\"Applications\":\"Applications\",\"Plans\":\"Plans\",\"Logout\":\"Logout\"}";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(languageString);
```

Comment: How is `languageString` going to even compile?

Comment: I didn't look that closely at his original code. Given that he provided no specifics about what error he was getting or where it was other than "on the anonymous object" I didn't even give the string a second look, figuring the problem was in the deserialization not in the compilation of the string (which most likely isn't the actual string he's trying to deserialize anyway).

Answer (score 1):

```
 var languageString = @"{""Projects"":""Projects"",""Dashboard"":""Dashboard"",""Applications"":""Applications"",""Plans"":""Plans"",""Logout"":""Logout""}";

        var objOut = new { Projects = "", Dashboard = "", Applications = "", Plans = "", Logout = "" };
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(languageString, objOut);
```

This will work for you.

with your code i did not get any error . Please explain your error in details

Answer (score 1):

I can't see *name* or *lastname* parameter inside your JSON string so I'm not sure what you're trying to do with it. Also, you should probably escape quotes if you're willing to compile your code actually. You could go with verbatim string (@) and double quotes or with backslash.

**Verbatim string:**

```
var languageString = @"{""Projects"":""Projects"",""Dashboard"":""Dashboard"",""Applications"":""Applications"",""Plans"":""Plans"",""Logout"":""Logout""}";
```

**Backslash:**

```
var languageString = "{\"Projects\":\"Projects\",\"Dashboard\":\"Dashboard\",\"Applications\":\"Applications\",\"Plans\":\"Plans\",\"Logout\":\"Logout\"}";
```

Now when you got that string right, you should create a proper class that's a match for your JSON if you're willing to deserialize it. Your anonymous class should look something like this:

```
var objOut = new
{
    Projects = "",
    Dashboard = "",
    Applications = "",
    Plans = "",
    Logout = ""
};
```

With all that settled, you will retrieve your JSON values inside instance of an object of your anonymous class.